# How do you process an array outside the vue instance and assign the processed data to a (currently empty) array inside the vue instance?

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js

I have an array of blog post inside a script tag on the page that looks like this:

```
var posts = [ 
    {article_name: "name", category: "test".....}, 
    {article_name: "name2", category: "test2".....},
    {...}
]
```

There are 30 objects in each array.  I need to grab the categories in each object and assign it to the data prop in a vue instance. I have an empty array inside the vue instance like:

```
var blog_posts_nav = new Vue({
    el: '#blog-posts-nav',
    data: {
        tags: []
    }
})
```

I want to have each individual "category" in the 30 objects mapped to the "tags" array in the data prop. I tried doing it via the `created()` hook but it seems that the created hook can't access data? I tried:

```
created() {
    posts.forEach( function (item) {
        this.tags.push(item.category)
    });
}
```

But I get an error in the console that says `tags` is `undefined`. Any help how I would deal with this? Basically I want to do work on a set of data and assign it to an array inside vue before outputting it to the page and in a manner that vue can interact with the data.

**So first and foremost, is the `created()` hook (or any hook) the best way to go about this? Or should I be using something like `methods` or `computed`?**

What is the "best practices" way and how would I go about achieving this?

Comment: Created happens before the component state is set up. Use beforeMount tinstead https://vuejs.org/v2/api/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not the `created()` method that can't access `this`, it's the inner context of `forEach`.

You can capture `this` to a local constant first, then access it inside the loop.

```js
console.clear()

var posts = [ 
  {article_name: "name", category: "test" }, 
  {article_name: "name2", category: "test2" },
]

Vue.component("tags",{
  template:`
    <div>
      {{tags}}
    </div>
  `,
  data(){
    return {
      tags: [],
    }
  },
  created() {
    const vm = this;
    console.log('created', vm.tags)
    posts.forEach( function (item) {
      vm.tags.push(item.category)
      console.log('created, posts.forEach', vm.tags)
    });
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: "#app"
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.3/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <tags></tags>
</div>
```

Comment: This worked but I also managed to achieve the same thing with an arrow function. Instead of forEach(function(item)) I did forEach( item => { rest of the code here }) which cuts out the need for the constant.